# Slice of structs behaviour

Tags: pointers, go, struct, slice, composite-literals

When we declare a slice of structs, but set the data type to a pointer to the struct, does go automatically convert the literals to pointers?

```golang
type book struct {
    id int
    name string
}

var books = []*book {
    {1, "Yellow moon"}, // ---> Is this a pointer to book OR just book
}
```

Comment: It's a pointer to book, of course, because you can't store anything else than that in a slice of pointer to book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to define with and without type:

https://play.golang.org/p/CB2MDPDztrc

Answer (score 2):

It will be a pointer to `book`, same as `&book{1, "Yellow moon"}`, but the spec allows to elide the type and the `&` operator, because it's obvious from the type.

```
var books = []*book {
    {1, "Yellow moon"},  // This is the same as &book{1, "Yellow moon"}
}
```

[Spec: Composite literals:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

> Within a composite literal of array, slice, or map type `T`, elements or map keys that are themselves composite literals may elide the respective literal type if it is identical to the element or key type of `T`. Similarly, elements or keys that are addresses of composite literals may elide the `&T` when the element or key type is `*T`.
>
> ```
> [][]Point{{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}}  // same as [][]Point{[]Point{Point{0, 1}, Point{1, 2}}}
>
> [2]*Point{{1.5, -3.5}, {}}   // same as [2]*Point{&Point{1.5, -3.5}, &Point{}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`Does go auto convert composite literals inside a slice to pointers if I declare the slice as a pointer to a struct?`

it is default behavior of pointer to struct

> To access the field X of a struct when we have the struct pointer p we could write (*p).X. However, that notation is cumbersome, so the language permits us instead to write just p.X, without the explicit dereference.

https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/4

Comment: What does field access have to do with struct literals?

Comment: hmm i think i got it wrong, i thought what he mean by literal is field, sorry